# How to identify if the JVM thats running is Driver or Executor in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to extend Spark logging to Elasticsearch. And I am looking for a way to identity whether this message is logged by the driver or from executors while building the log statement.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Anything within a transformation (map, flatMap, filter etc) will be performed on the executors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to give you the example using the following code to differentiate between driver and executor,

```
object test{
    def main(args:Array[String]){
        log.info("This is driver")
        val sparkSession = ???

        spark.read
        ...
        .map(x=>{
            ...
            log.info("This is executor")
            ...
            })

        log.info("This is driver")
    }
}
```

As you can see that anything in between `map`/ `foreach` and other transformations/ actions is executed on executors, everything else is executed on driver.

Hope this clarifies.